# Implementing WindowListener Error

Tags: java, swing, windowlistener

Hello I'm having a problem with adding a WindowListener to my JFrame... It's saying "windowClosing can't be resolved to a type" and I don't know how to fix the error.

```
public Editor() {
    //Create JFrame For Editor
    JFrame SimplyHTMLJFrame = new JFrame();

    SimplyHTMLJFrame.setTitle("Simply HTML - Editor");
    SimplyHTMLJFrame.setSize(800, 600);
    SimplyHTMLJFrame.setResizable(true);
    SimplyHTMLJFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    SimplyHTMLJFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
    SimplyHTMLJFrame.addWindowListener(new windowClosing()); //The error is here it underlines windowClosing in red
    SimplyHTMLJFrame.setVisible(true);
    System.out.println("Editor - JFrame 'SimplyHTMLJFrame' - Created");

    //Program Closing Alert
    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
        int result = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Are you sure you want to quit?\n"
                    + "All unsaved changes will be lost!","Confirm", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION,JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
        if (result == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
            System.exit(0);
        } else {
            //Do nothing
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to implement an inner class for the WindowListener callback.

```
public class Editor {

  public Editor() {

    // Create JFrame For Editor
    JFrame SimplyHTMLJFrame = new JFrame();

    SimplyHTMLJFrame.setTitle("Simply HTML - Editor");
    SimplyHTMLJFrame.setSize(800, 600);
    SimplyHTMLJFrame.setResizable(true);
    SimplyHTMLJFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    SimplyHTMLJFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);

    SimplyHTMLJFrame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
      // Program Closing Alert
      public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
        int result = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Are you sure you want to quit?\n" + "All unsaved changes will be lost!", "Confirm", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION, JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);

        if (result == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {

          System.exit(0);

        } else {

          // Do nothing

        }
      }
    }); // The error is here it underlines windowClosing in red

    SimplyHTMLJFrame.setVisible(true);
    System.out.println("Editor - JFrame 'SimplyHTMLJFrame' - Created");

  }
```

Comment: Thank you I've picked yours as the answer because yours is the one I used to solve my problem!

Answer (score 2):

`new windowClosing()` is not a class, so you can't instantiate it. You have two options.

- Make the class `implements WindowListener` and use `.addWindowListener(this)`.
- Or, create an annonymous class

  ```
  SimplyHTMLJFrame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter(){
       @Override
       public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
       ....
  });
  ```

Note, if you choose method one, you will need to implements all the window listener methods below You can leave the ones you don't need, empty methods, but they *still* all need to be overridden. If you choose the second method, you can just use a `WindowAdapter` and just override the methods you need.

```
@Override
public void windowOpened(WindowEvent e) {}

@Override
public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {}

@Override
public void windowClosed(WindowEvent e) {}

@Override
public void windowIconified(WindowEvent e) {}

@Override
public void windowDeiconified(WindowEvent e) {}

@Override
public void windowActivated(WindowEvent e) {}

@Override
public void windowDeactivated(WindowEvent e) {}
```

---

As a side note, it's good practice to use the `@Override` annotation for method that is being overriden, so you know that you are correctly overriding a method.

Answer (score 1):

The mistake you have done is, you are instantiating a method instead of a type

```
SimplyHTMLJFrame.addWindowListener(new windowClosing());
```

here `windowClosing` is a method in your `JFrame` class

You need to create our own `WindowAdapter`/`WindowListener` and add it as listener to your `JFrame`

Create a separate class in same/other package

```
class MyWindowAdapter extends WindowAdapter {

    @Override
    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
        int result = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Are you sure you want to quit?\n"
                + "All unsaved changes will be lost!","Confirm", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION,JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);

        if (result == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {

            System.exit(0);

        } else {

            //Do nothing

        }
    }


}
```

add it to your `JFrame` `Editor`

```
SimplyHTMLJFrame.addWindowListener(new MyWindowAdapter());
```

Comment: Thank you for replying so fast, but how would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 0):

`windowClosing()` is the name of a method and not a class that can be instantiated.

You need to pass an instance of a WindowListener to `SimplyHTMLJFrame.addWindowListener`. Assuming that your `Editor` class either `implements WindowListener` or `extends WindowAdapter`, an assumption I'm making based on the presence of the `windowClosing` method, this line would be valid.

```
SimplyHTMLJFrame.addWindowListener(this);
```